# How to store the value of resultset as an int?

Tags: java, jdbc

I need to open a div tag from jsp if the value of the resultset is more than 30000. But how to store the value of rs as an int?

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");                              
    con = DriverManager.getConnection (urlPrefix, "uname", "pwd");
    System.out.println("got connection");
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    String strQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM  tablename where condition stmt";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(strQuery);
    if (rs>30000) {
        request.getParameter("view");
    }
    System.out.println("executed query");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation and tutorials, it will help to understand how JDBC works.

Answer (score 2):

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(strQuery);
```

stmt.executeQuery return a ResultSet object and from the object we can retrive the result of
the query like below for your case.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(strQuery);
int count=0;
if(rs.next()){
    count=rs.getInt(1);
}
```